# Fastest method for fingerprinting an array (calculating a unique hash from an array of data)

Tags: php, arrays, hash, fingerprint

I am using a lot of caching and buffering of API calls in my WWW Framework and one of the things that I end up using all around is 'fingerprinting' data in order to match cache filenames as well as detecting API calls that have already been made.

A lot of data is moved in arrays, like GET, POST and so on. As a result the uniqueness of an API call depends on the data.

As a result I need to fingerprint this information. To do it requires generating a 'fingerprint' from the data array as well and hashing it into a string that I can store and compare against.

For array serialization there is serialize() and json_encode() in PHP. After various benchmarks I consider json_encode() the faster method for serializing an array and am quite happy with it.

For hashing there is md5() and sha1() functions, of which md5() is faster according to my benchmarks.

So my current fingerprint algorithm is:

```
$fingerprint=md5(json_encode($array));
```

But I am having doubts whether this is the 'fastest possible' method for fingerprinting an array in PHP. I have tried Google and StackOverflow and have not found good alternatives though. Am I on a right track or do I need to do something different?

Comment: How does `md5(var_export($data, true))` compare? Also - wonder if you can rely on order to be preserved by `json_encode`. It would be bad to miss a cache because key order was different.

Comment: var_export() is faster than serialize() but slower than json_encode() according to my tests. I'm looking into crc32() to replace md5(), need to test.

Comment: Well, apparently (to my surprise) crc32() is actually slower than md5() and of course is more prone to possible collisions. So I'm back where I was before at md5(json_encode($array));

Comment: I think you've squeezed about as much as you can out of it. You might consider just storing/analyzing the GET/POST variables themselves, or even the JSON string. I don't know if you have considered it but if the GET/POST is in a different order it will have a completely different fingerprint.

Comment: Also, I hear hash('md5',"") is faster, and hash('md4',"") even faster than that. You would have to test it on your own system though.

Comment: I am not worried about the order of GET/POST variables and their sub-variables. Performance wise it does not matter what the order is, even if it generates a new fingerprint if the order is different (sorting GET/POST every time would be too much of a performance hit considering the small gain and I only use it for API validation for secure API calls). Since API is automated, most of the calls will always have the same 'order' anyway (since it's another system that makes the call and not a 'user', and systems don't tend to intentionally randomize the order of variables.)
But anyways, thanks!

Comment: Oh and actually md5() is fraction faster than hash('md5'), just tested it. hash('md4') is fraction faster than both of them, but I'll stay with md5() for now due to having less experience with md4 and it's potential pitfalls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've got your array `json_encoded`, you should probably go with a non-cyrptographic hash function if you're primarily concerned with speed. Different hash functions are good for different things. MD5 and Sha1 are called cryptographic because they are hard to reverse (note they are widely considered deprecated for security purposes due to vulnerabilities). CRC  (cyclic redundancy check) functions are error detecting codes and would be ill-suited for uniqueness anyways.

Wikipedia is a decent place to start for this, if only because contributions there generally have external links to library implementations: [List of hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions). I would recommend reading up on a few of the non-cryptographic libraries there and benchmarking them. The non-cryptographic functions are more written for speed and reasonable degrees of uniqueness, sacrificing security, error detection and other interesting properties, which from your description is exactly what you want.

One final note to consider if you're mainly concerned about speed is how you are going to store and compare the fingerprints themselves. MD5 outputs 128 bits of data, which won't fit into a numeric type in php without some extra library calls and overhead. For my money, I would bet that you could get the best speed of comparison and storage would come from an hash function that can output 64 bit numbers directly. Note that to get 64 numbers natively in php, you need to have 64 bit hardware and have php configured/installed in 64 bit mode. I have some code around here somewhere I used to test our staging and prod environments I could probably dig up if you're interested.

Btw, I don't think you're going to get any faster stringification of an array than json-encode. The heart of that problem is array walking and string manipulation, so essentially the speed is proportional to the verbosity of the output. JSON-encode is very terse compared to php's serialize or export functions. I bet if you looked through enough comments on the php documentation pages, you could find someone who wrote a hash function that takes an array as an input directly, but it would be a gamble whether it was any good at all.

Feel free to ask questions if I was unclear on anything.

Comment: Not the best of answers, but considering circumstances it's good enough. Thanks for your help!

Comment: one of the circumstances being its uniqueness here, I'd say it *is* the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

I tested various methods on 7000 arrays in 100 loops and fastest is `crc32(serialize($arr))` (avg. 0.65 sec)

```
    $arr = ['name' => $name, 'category' => $category, 'hits' => $hits];

    md5(var_export($arr, true));
    md5(serialize($arr));
    md5(json_encode($arr));

    hash('md5', var_export($arr, true), "");
    hash('md5', serialize($arr), "");
    hash('md5', json_encode($arr), "");

    hash('md4', var_export($arr, true), "");
    hash('md4', serialize($arr), "");
    hash('md4', json_encode($arr), "");

    crc32(var_export($arr, true));
    crc32(serialize($arr));
    crc32(json_encode($arr));

    sha1(var_export($arr, true));
    sha1(serialize($arr));
    sha1(json_encode($arr));

    spl_object_hash((object) $arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that [@Patrick M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1146608/patrick-m) explanation is really good, I just want to add some extra data here.

As [@Patrick M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1146608/patrick-m) said, [md5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) is a cryptographic hash, which will make some extra efforts to add security (even if nowadays is deprecated for that purpose).

You can check which [hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) functions you have available with [hash_algos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php) function.

However, here you can see a [benchmark of those algorithms](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php#89574), where it says (I didn't try myself) that the faster is `md4`, and then [md5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php), etc.

To be fair, the benchmark should use the specific function as well, if any, to be sure ([md5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php), [sha1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php), [crc32](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php),...), as it may be faster (or slower, who knows).

In conclusion, I think that your approach looks like a pretty good one.

Just keep in mind that [md5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) is not secure, as it's described in the [PHP's Password Hashing FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash), so if you need to store credit cards fingerprints or something of sorts (that I don't think it's your case), you may need another function as well as adding some extra steps.

As an alternative, you may want to check [spl_object_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php).